# Apache 2.4 не хочет обслуживать статические файлы Django 2.2

Tags: python, django, apache, apache-modules

Всем привет, я новичок в django и недавно сделал пет-проект и хотел залить его на сервер ubuntu 18.04. На нем стоит Apache 2.4. В проекте(django 2.2) я отключил режим отладки и добавил необходимые хосты. Для того чтобы сервер обслуживал статические файлы установил mod_wsgi файл на апачи и заполнил его

```
Alias /media/ /var/www/djstar/media/
Alias /static/admin/ usr/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin
Alias /static/ /var/www/djstar/assets

<Directory /var/www/djstar/assets>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory usr/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/djstar/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/djstar/djstar/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/djstar


<Directory /var/www/djstar/djstar>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Но статические файлы не обслуживаются. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема. Спасибо!

Comment: 1. Почему `usr/lib/site-packages`, без слэша впереди? 2. Какой код ответа приходит от сервера (403, 404, 500)? 3. Что логируется при запросе? Частая проблема - у апача нет прав на чтение файлов.

Comment: Слэш в файле стоит, приходит ответ 404 для картинок и стилей ксс, дал 755 права файлу, не помогло

Comment: Изменение "Order deny,allow
Allow from all"  на  "Reauire all granted" ничего не дало

Comment: Если 404, скорее всего, пути неправильно ресолвятся. Проверяй по файлам, к примеру, если `http://example.com/static/foo.css` кидает 404 в консоли браузера, смотри `readlink -f /var/www/djstar/assets/foo.css` и т.д.